# expected expression in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void num7()
{
    int numRows;
    cin >> numRows;
    for (int x = 0; x < numRows/2; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= x; y++) {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    float numRowsfloat = numRows;
    double cos = numRowsfloat / 2;
    int tan = numRowsfloat / 2;
    double sin = tan;
    if (cos == sin)
        cout << "\n";
        for (int x = 0; x < numRows/2; x++) {
            for (int y = numRows/2; y >0; y--) {
                cout << "*";
            }
        }
    else
        for (int x = 0; x < numRows/2+1; x++) {
            for (int y = x; y >0; y--) {
                cout << "*";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }

}
```

In the else column, it says expected expression.
This is trying to make a triangular shape. like

```
*
**
***
***
**
*
```

for inputed 6
or

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

for inputed 5

Comment: Put starting and closing braces for conditional statement and compile your code again.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is this:

```
if (cos == sin)
    cout << "\n";
    for (int x = 0; x < numRows/2; x++) {
        for (int y = numRows/2; y >0; y--) {
            cout << "*";
        }
    }
```

Here only the `cout` is part of the `if` statement. The loop is not. You need to add braces around the whole block.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the braces for the if statement. try this:

```
if (cos == sin) {
    cout << "\n";
    for (int x = 0; x < numRows/2; x++) {
        for (int y = numRows/2; y >0; y--) {
            cout << "*";
        }
    }
} else
    for (int x = 0; x < numRows/2+1; x++) {
        for (int y = x; y >0; y--) {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
```